# Timer for each level godot 3.1

Tags: timer, godot-3

I want to set a timer for each level of my game, so that when the player eats item number one, 10 seconds will be added to the time of that level, and when the player eats item number two, 5 seconds will be subtracted from the time of that level.
The total playing time in each level should be 60 seconds.
How can I script it?

And to display the timer in the scene of each level (60:00), should I use a special command?

Answer (score 0):

Before we get into Godot specific stuff: What you want is a countdown.

*Do not confuse this with a stopwatch, which counts up, and then you stop it and see the time it war running for.*

---

We could implement a countdown over something that ticks over time.

You could have - for example - a one second timer that decrements a variable with the remaining time. However, since you want fractions of seconds, assuming you don't need more precision than a frame, let us use `_process` directly instead.

It is trivial to increment the remaining time, since that is just incrementing the variable. And to check if the remaining time is over the upper bound is trivial too.

You get pauses for free. When the game is paused, the timer does not trigger the code to decrement the remaining time, so the countdown is automatically stopped.

---

Something like this:

```
extends Node
class_name Countdown


signal time_up
signal time_changed(seconds)


export var max_seconds:float setget set_max_seconds
var remaining_seconds:float setget set_remaining_seconds


func _ready() -> void:
    self.remaining_seconds = max_seconds


func _process(delta: float) -> void:
    self.remaining_seconds -= delta


func set_max_seconds(mod_value:float) -> void:
    max_seconds = max(0.0, mod_value)
    self.remaining_seconds = min(remaining_seconds, max_seconds)


func set_remaining_seconds(mod_value:float) -> void:
    mod_value = clamp(mod_value, 0.0, max_seconds)
    if remaining_seconds == mod_value:
        return

    remaining_seconds = mod_value
    emit_signal("time_changed", mod_value)
    if mod_value == 0.0:
        emit_signal("time_up")
```

Any other scripts that tries to set `max_seconds` or `remaining_seconds` will result in a call to the corresponding set method (`set_max_seconds` and `set_remaining_seconds` respectively.

From the same script - in Godot 3.x - that is not true. Instead we have to use `self` to trigger the set method. For example setting the `remaining_seconds` with `self` (`self.remaining_seconds`) will trigger the set method `set_remaining_seconds`.

Notice I'm setting the `remaining_seconds` to `max_seconds` at the start. Also that `max_seconds` is an exported variable (so you set it from the inspector). *If you hard code `max_seconds` (perhaps as a `const`) so it does not need a set method, you can make the code shorter.*

---

The other thing you want is to show it, which will require adding a `Label` to your UI.

I have added a signal `"time_changed"` to the script above, that you can connect to a method that formats and sets the text to the `Label`.

```
func _on_Countdown_time_changed(seconds:float) -> void:
    text = str(seconds)
```

**Addendum**: This is one solution to format the time: `("%02.2f" % seconds).replace(".", ":")`.

Since it is changing every frame anyway, you could use `_process` to read the value. Although I have made it so the `"time_changed"` stops triggering when it is not ticking (e.g. when it reached zero). In fact, the check `remaining_seconds == mod_value` will prevent triggering the signal, if there is no change in value. *If you consider that you don't need `"time_changed"`, you might remove it to make the code shorter.*

Speaking of reaching zero, there is also a `time_up` signal you can connect for that.

---

And you say that when the player gets an item it increments the time. So you need to find a reference to the countdown. Which brings the question of where do you place it. It could be on the root of the edited scene, like this:

```
Main
└ Countdown
```

Then you can find it like this:

```
owner.get_node("Countdown")
```

And as part of your collision you would so something like this:

```
func _on_Area_body_entered(body):
    # ...
    owner.get_node("Countdown").remaining_seconds += 10.0
```

Comment: thank you
According to your description, should I create the countdown in a separate scene and write this script for it and then import it into each level?
Or should I add these codes to the script player?
I was a little confused.

Comment: And Is countdown a ready node like the timer in Godot?
Or should I make a node2D myself and call it Countdown?

Comment: @NinaMonti The `Countdown` does not need an scene. The script is standalone. Not to be part of the player character. It is a custom class, not part of Godot. I made it extend a `Node` not a `Node2D` or any other derived class because it does need a 2D position, nor a 3D position. Make a script for the `Countdown` class with the code I provided. Since `Countdown` is a named class, it should appear as an option when you try to add a new node. You could also attaching to an existing `Node` like any other script.

Comment: @NinaMonti See [Classes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html?highlight=class_name#classes).